# Can you use Integrated Windows Authentication out-of-browser?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, windows-authentication

I have a WCF service that is being consumed by two clients:

1. A Silverlight client; this works fine with IWA.
2. A desktop application

I want to use IWA in the desktop application, but is that possible? I'm getting an HTTP error message saying I'm passing in Anonymous, when it wants Negotiate or NTLM. Sounds pretty obvious, but how can I fix this?

Comment: We can only help find your mistake in the code if you post it.  It certainly is possible.

Comment: From a couple of sources it sounds like you need to regenerate your service reference after changing the server to Windows authentication only and that'll sort it out - that doesn't sound convincing to me though. There's also a [ClientCredentials property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms553830.aspx) of the WCF client object you can set.

Comment: @Rup is right that you need to set the web site/application in IIS to only accept Integrated Windows authentication. Configure the service and and client like this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1646707.aspx/1) The answer in the MSDN forum [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/0aac0110-187e-4a00-a597-f15b768cf16c/) shows client code to send the Windows credentials from your desktop app.

Comment: Sorry, I have got it working with the Silverlight client. So IIS is correctly configured as far as I'm aware. My issue right now is with the bindings in my desktop app.config; should it only reflect the Silverlight config file? Or should it also reflect the web.config file? Because it sounds as if it should do both - have the endpoint as the SL config file has, but also the transport mode that the web.config file contains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this. It does turn out that you need to essentially mix the web.config and client config files into the app.config file of your desktop application.

So you'd need to add the web.config lines:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  </system.web>
```

and

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="winAuthenticationBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

(obviously put within the `<system.serviceModel>` tag.

And then use that binding with the client endpoint that you'd normally put in in a client config file.

Comment: Is this for the Silverlight application when it is OOB?  I'm running into this issue, and it's when I'm running OOB.

Comment: @RichardB Yes, this was for OOB. I don't specifically remember the entire solution, but it definitely is possible.

Comment: ok.  Ill keep digging... Hitting an "It works on my machine" but not in deployment issue with Windows Authentication... tried to build a quick windows forms application, and get "Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service."

Comment: @Harry... did you have to add either /clientaccesspolicy.xml or /crossdomain.xml to the application by chance?

Comment: So far.. narrowed down to a Ninject Service Host factory issue... still digging.

Comment: I'm devving on IIS Express, but deploying on IIS 6.0... IIS 6.0 still needs to have the AspNetCompatibilityRequirements() attribute on the service class... what a waste of 6 hours.

Answer (score 0):

While there isn't a lot to look at here to help diagnose the issue, I would suggest you look over this resource and see what your desktop application is missing:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629363.aspx

It is my assumption that since your Silverlight application runs server-side, the issue is passing your authentication over the network rather than just inside the server network.  The other possibility is that you have a custom configuration for your Silverlight application that you haven't brought over for your desktop application.  For example, you can change the authentication mechanism inside the config file from the default that comes with the WSDL to something else.  Maybe that is what the Silverlight application developer did and you just need to mimic it.

Answer (score 0):

When your desktop application starts, the first thing you should do in Program.cs is this:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
```

By default CurrentPrincipal is the GenericPrincipal, which is not authenticated. Also, remember you'll need to execute that code on any threads you spin up as well.

You'll also need to configure Wcf so that it connects to your service, probably similar to how you configured it for Silverlight.